# Cannot use the same private key and public key to access two accounts

Tags: ssh

We want to access two different accounts on a server from a client with the same private key and public key, like this:

`ssh -i /public_dir/id_rsa account_a@remove_server`

`ssh -i /public_dir/id_rsa account_b@remove_server`

The public key has been added to `authorized_keys` of two accounts, and all the permissions of file and dir are good. 
But we find that ssh to `account_b` failed, and ssh to `account_a` success. Does ssh not allow this behavior?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check if `sshd_config` files on two machines differ?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Hi Remeo, thanks for your reply. We have only one client and one server, and we try to login the server with two accounts.

Comment: Try with `ssh -v -v -v .....` and check the difference

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using the same ssh key for two different servers.